# why is b array not copy whole a array?

Tags: c, pointers, memory-leaks

I am thinking this as b points to the first element of a thus it had the value of the first element.
   Now as b points to the first element we can access all the values in the a array .

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) 
{
  int *b,*a={0,0,0,0,0},i;
  b=(int*)malloc(5*sizeof(int));
  b=a;
  a = NULL;
  for(i=0;i<5;i++)
  {
    printf("%d",*(b+i));
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please clean up your presentation.

Comment: What did the compiler tell you about your code? I'm guessing it would have had some wise advice.

Comment: The compiler should be yelling at you for the initialization of `a`; that type of initializer is not valid for a pointer.

Comment: Compiler won't yell at you about it, but I will: "MEMORY LEAK ON LINE `b=a;`" ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You can't initialize the int pointer 'a' this way, the value of a it's a memory address not an int.

You can use a local variable "int a[]={0,0,0,0,0}" if you dont want alloc memory.

With the line "b=a" you are storing the address of a in b, and losing the memory previously allocated, you could do:
 "for(i=0;i<5;i++)b[i]=a[i];"